# Using CSS font-family to select Droid fonts not working on Android

Tags: android, fonts, font-face, font-family

I discovered that the following HTML code does not work on Android (it will only use the default font: Droid Sans. On desktop it is working as expected.

```
<p style='font-family: "Droid Sans",sans-serif;'>vând whisky și tequila, preț fix.</p>
<p style='font-family: "Droid Sans Mono",monospace;'>vând whisky și tequila, preț fix.</p>
<p style='font-family: "Droid Serif",serif;'>vând whisky și tequila, preț fix.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have an @font-face declaration for the other typefaces in your css. I imagine you only have one for Droid Sans. You need one for each typeface. For example, in your css you should have:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DroidSans';
    src: url('font/DroidSans-webfont.eot?') format('eot'),
         url('font/DroidSans-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('font/DroidSans-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('font/DroidSans-webfont.svg#webfontw7zqO19G') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'DroidSansMono';
    src: url('font/DroidSans-Mono-webfont.eot?') format('eot'),
         url('font/DroidSans-Mono-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('font/DroidSans-Mono-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('font/DroidSans-Mono-webfont.svg#webfontSOhoM6aS') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'DroidSerif';
    src: url('font/DroidSerif-webfont.eot?') format('eot'),
         url('font/DroidSerif-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('font/DroidSerif-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('font/DroidSerif-webfont.svg#webfontw7zqO19G') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

And then in your code, your font-family should be the same as those you declared in the css above (i.e. font-family: 'Droid Sans'; is not the same as font-family: 'DroidSans')

```
<p style='font-family: "DroidSans",sans-serif;'>vând whisky și tequila, preț fix.</p>
<p style='font-family: "DroidSansMono",monospace;'>vând whisky și tequila, preț fix.</p>
<p style='font-family: "DroidSerif",serif;'>vând whisky și tequila, preț fix.</p>
```

Try it and see how you get on.

Comment: By the way, you'll also need to make sure you have the correct fonts in the css. In the example above, all the font files should be in a sub-directory of the css called 'fonts'.

Comment: I'm not trying to use custom fonts, only the ones provided by the browser.

Comment: @tadywankenobi, the Android tag is not there because of the fonts ;)

Answer (score 1):

It seems Android only recognizes family names defined in [system_fonts.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/data/fonts/system_fonts.xml) ([fonts.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/gingerbread/data/fonts/fonts.xml) up to gingerbread).  E.g. to get Droid Serif you're suppossed to write the generic `serif`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22555625/239657) for details.

Oh, and there is a quirk with 'Droid Sans': that one name *is* in the config since 4.0 but the .ttf is a symlink to Roboto.

<speculation> I can see how early in Android's life someone said "we're only going to have *three* fonts so it's better if developers only use generic names, that way we can always replace them" </speculation>

But it's unfortunate.  There are many reasons why the actual font you'll get might be different:

- Before 4.0 you get the Droid family, after you get the Roboto family.
- Firefox is [bundling Open Sans and Charis SIL](http://ianbarlow.wordpress.com/2013/03/19/improved-type-on-firefox-for-android/) and using those instead.
- Manufacturers might replace the 3 fonts with their own.  EDIT: I can't find any confirmation this actually happens.

In all these situations it'd be nice if I could reference a specific font by actual name in my font stack.  Alas, I can't.