# Android sans-serif font

Tags: android, html, css, android-fonts

I realised recently that the Android Browser doesn't have any of the fonts I have in my font stack as a Times Replacement with the help from http://www.codestyle.org/css/font-family/index.shtml.

```css
"Times New Roman",Times,FreeSerif,"DejaVu Serif",serif
```

I'm not angry about it, because it looks nice. But I want to know what is the font's name so  that I can include it into my font stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original Android font was "Droid" (Serif version is "Droid Serif"): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droid_(font)

The font in the newer devices is "Roboto", though I'm not sure if it has a serif version.

Comment: What are these newer devices? Android 4.0?

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need to add a name, since the Android browser checks your current list, notices that none of the specific names matches, and uses `serif`, which is mapped to the browser’s serif font. Similarly for the Android sans-serif font (which is what your heading refers to...), use just the generic name `sans-serif`.

Oddly enough, the often-advertised name `Droid Serif` does *not* work. It is just yet another unrecognized name to the Android browser. See e.g. the question [Using CSS font-family to select Droid fonts not working on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078008/using-css-font-family-to-select-droid-fonts-not-working-on-android) (the question is more useful than the comments and answers).

Comment: Thanks for the info. It is not the answer to my question though it was helpful.